# Amcharts : small (sometimes 0px) chart height on page load (in default tab)

Tags: height, size, amcharts, bootstrap-tabs

I have an Amcharts in a tab but when it is created on page load, it is compressed with an incorrect (too small and sometimes to 0px) height. When I switch tab and come back to the chart tab, then I can clearly see that it is resized and looks perfectly after some visible height changes.

I have seen a bunch of similar topics, but they all complain about the chart having a small size only when arriving on a tab and not on page load directly.

I have tried to call `invalidateSize()`, `validateNow()`, etc. after the chart is built on page load (even with a timeout) but it doesn't do the job.

Is it because of the container that wouldn't give enough info to Amcharts to process the correct size? How come Amcharts is able to recalculate the size of the charts when changing the tab and back to the chart one?

Would you please have any hints for me? Thank you very much

I use Bootstrap tabs system.

Comment: Try adding this line into chart config `autoDisplay: true`. If it works, I'll post a better explanation as an answer.

Comment: Thank you martynasma, although it still didn't do the work. It didn't change anything :/

Comment: Hello, I have the same problem. How did you finally solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I have finally solved it by setting a fixed height

```
.amcharts-chart-div{
  height: 436px !important;
}
```